# System.IO,FileLoadException Error when application runs

Tags: c#

I am having a very odd issue. I have done some research online in regards to this but none of the answers seem to help. This application was compiling and running properly a couple days ago, now it just errors out with the following error. Any suggestions on what I can do to resolve the issue? I really don't know where to go from here.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx'

Comment: Are you using NuGet to reference assemblies? If so, try getting latest versions of NewtonSoft.Json library and then rebuild.  This usually happens if you do not have the referenced library available at the location.

Comment: I installed the new version of Newtonsoft.Json, but it's still looking for this older version of it.

Comment: Can you try going to VS and then right click on your Solution and select "Manage NUGet packages". Then select Updates and then nuget.org. See if you have any updates.

Comment: I just did that, and there were no updates available. Is there a way to change the version that it's looking for I seem to have 4.5.00 and it's looking for 4.0.5.0

Comment: Did you use any third party libraries? You might have a library that has dependency to an older version of `Json.NET` (`Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0`)...

Comment: that is correct. I found reference to it in my dropbox.api lib. didn't even see that the first time around. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My next steps would be to do the following:

1. Remove this in all projects using NuGet.
2. Go into the NuGet package repository and delete the files for Newtonsoft.Json. (they shouldn't still be there but if they are, it indicates a problem with NuGet and more troubleshooting there is required - in my experience, NuGet works about 30% of the time, and the rest of the time it is a pain in the ass).
3. Manually delete all the bin and obj folders in your project(s).
4. Re-add the Json library via NuGet.

If that doesn't work, please tell that as well.

Comment: where would the repository be stored?

Comment: usually in the solution root folder. Should be "packages."

Comment: ok so did all that above, installed from NuGet...and continued to get the same error as above. I remembered I had backed up my project folder a few weeks ago. I fould a folder in the packages folder that specifically was named "Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.5"
Copied it into my current folder and now it works fine. Thank you for the help. I am worried that eventually that version of newtonsoft might be discontinued. Is there a way to allow multi version dependencies?

Comment: Different versions of the same library in the same solution can cause lots of headaches. I recommend continuing your troubleshooting until you are able to eliminate this issue. I find that sticking the DLL in a "External References" folder and referencing directly (no Nuget) works for me.